# How to control jenkins jobs using chef

Tags: groovy, jenkins, chef-infra

I am wondering how can I control Jenkins jobs using chef recipes. I researched and found two possible ways as follow.

1) Create job using UI and save the job using jenkins cli(export your job)

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myjenkins.com get-job myjob > myjob.xml
```

then use myjob.xml as template for the job and import the template on each chef run.

2) Other way is to use jenkins dsl plugin and write your job is groovy.

Are these correct way for managing Jenkins job using chef or there are other ways around?

Comment: @coderanger Thanks but this is just as using the template for the job.Consider the case where we are changing 50 plus jobs in a day,how will we managing templates then.

isn't there some dynamic option for controlling the jobs,where we don't have to refer templates or can templates be made dynamic with attributes.How to implement that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poise Jenkins cookbook has a resource for [jenkins_job](https://github.com/poise/jenkins#jenkins_job).

Comment: Thanks but this is just as using the template for the job.Consider the case where we are changing 50 plus jobs in a day,how will we managing templates then.

isn't there some dynamic option for controlling the jobs,where we don't have to refer templates or can templates be made dynamic with attributes.How to implement that solution.

Comment: You just stated the solution yourself. Use a single template for all your jobs and fill in details via resources. See https://github.com/balanced-cookbooks/balanced-ci/blob/master/libraries/balanced_ci_job.rb for an example, it subclasses JenkinsJob (via CiJob) and adds all the stuff specific to Balanced's job structure. In that cookbook you'll also see the code for BalancedCiPipeline which knits multiple jobs together into a CD pipeline.